# MFC SDI application parse custom parameter

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a SDI application established in Visual Studio. I understood passing a file name to an application is fine like in the commandline: `MyApp.exe "C:\a.txt"`. However it will not accept custom arguments or URLs. Say I cannot do `MyApp.exe "SomethingILike"` or `MyApp.exe "www.google.com"`

I understand the code to process arguments are in the `...App::InitInstance()` There are

```
CCommandLineInfo cmdInfo;
ParseCommandLine(cmdInfo);

if (!ProcessShellCommand(cmdInfo))
    return FALSE;
m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
m_pMainWnd->UpdateWindow();
```

Obviously the `ProcessShellCommand` rules out the arguments MFC does not think reasonable. How should I process my custom arguments? Say I want to pass "SomethingILike", now it tells me file-not-found and shuts off, but at least I want the application to start normally and I will have a chance to get

```
this->m_lpCmdLine
```

I cannot comment out the `ProcessShellCommand` if statement, otherwise it gives me an unhandled exception. Probably `ProcessShellCommand` does some initialization work too, which sounds not quite reasonable to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to derive a class from `CCommandLineInfo` and override its virtual function [`ParseParam()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bss6bxss.aspx) to define your own processing of the parameters.

Here a [demo](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/317374/how-to-pass-arguments-froma-program-to-a-mfc-based) on how to do it.